# Create a command to reduce code duplication when inserting imgage

Tags: macros, graphics, includegraphics, scripts, subfig

so I have to do a pdf with a lot of images and I would like to avoid code duplication, so I'd like to create something like a function which take as input two arguments:

1. Image name
2. Caption text

So that this function code should be:

```
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image_name}
   \subcaption*{Caption}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

So instead of writing the above code for each image I would like only to write something like :

\my_function(Image_name,Caption_test)

Is this possible ?
Thank you

Comment: `\newcommand\myfunction[2]{\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
   \subcaption*{#2}
 \end{subfigure}}`